# PHP While Loop in a single database table to fetch belongings - Tree View

Tags: php, mysql, json, tree, treeview

Dears, So I have a database table defining objects as below:

[image: Text]

And a table defining relations between the above objects:

[image: Text]

And using foreach and while loops I'm trying to fetch the belongings in this table where the result I expect is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "object": 1,
    "name": "TEST1",
    "children": [
      {
        "object": 2,
        "name": "TEST2",
        "children": [
          {
            "object": 3,
            "name": "TEST3",
            "children": [
              {
                "object": 4,
                "name": "TEST4",
                "children": [
                  null
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "object": 3,
        "name": "TEST3",
        "children": [
          {
            "object": 4,
            "name": "TEST4",
            "children": [
              null
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object": 2,
    "name": "TEST2",
    "children": [
      {
        "object": 3,
        "name": "TEST3",
        "children": [
          {
            "object": 4,
            "name": "TEST4",
            "children": [
              null
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object": 3,
    "name": "TEST3",
    "children": [
      {
        "object": 4,
        "name": "TEST4",
        "children": [
          null
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried the following code:

```
$resultArray = array();

foreach ($objects as $object) { // FOR EACH OBJECT

    $childrenArray = array(); // SET CHILDREN ARRAY FOR CURRENT OBJECT

    $object_id = $object['object_id']; // CURRENT OBJECT'S ID
    $object_name = $object['name']; // CURRENT OBJECT'S NAME
    $children = getChildren($object_id); // RETURNS ARRAY OF CHILDREN BELONGING TO THE CURRENT OBJECT

    foreach ($children as $child) {

        $child_id = $child['object_id']; // CURRENT CHILD'S ID
        $child_name = $child['name']; // CURRENT CHILD'S NAME
        $childrenChild = getChildren($child_id); // RETURNS ARRAY OF CHILDREN BELONGING TO THE CURRENT CHILD

        $childrenArray[] = array('object' => $child_id, 'name' => $child_name, 'children' => $childrenChild);
    }

    $resultArray[] = array('object' => $object_id, 'name' => $object_name, 'children' => $childrenArray); // CURRENT OBJECT'S ARRAY WITH ITS CHILDREN AS AN ARRAY

}
```

And that's all I could reach, I'm lost and my brain is burned :(

Comment: Don't use PHP, use a recursive CTE (MySQL-8.0 / MariaDB-10.2+)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it, I think I lost some hair :)

```
function belongingsToObject($id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `object_relation` WHERE `object_id_parent` = '$id'";
    $database = new database();
    $result = $database->query($query);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = array('object_id' => $row['object_id_child'], 'object_relations' => belongingsToObject($row['object_id_child']));
    }
    return $data;
}

$belongingsToObject = belongingsToObject(1);

$object_relations = array();

foreach ($belongingsToObject as $belonging) {

    $object_relations[] = array('object_id' => $belonging['object_id'], 'object_relations' => belongingsToObject($belonging['object_id']));
}

$object = array('object_id' => "1", 'object_relations' => $object_relations);

echo json_encode($object);
```